# share_plus does not share the text flutter

Tags: flutter, share

I am trying to implement sharing widget as a screenshot via share_plus.dart plug in. It works, however it does not attach the string text to the widget. How do I fix that?

```
Future<void> shareReview() async {
final image = await controller.capture();
saveAndShare(image);
}

void saveAndShare(Uint8List bytes) async {
final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
final image = File('${directory.path}/review.png');
image.writeAsBytesSync(bytes);

final text = 'blahblahblahbalh';
await Share.shareFiles([image.path], text: text);
}
```